# Linux library calls ambiguously named function in executable - is this possible?

Tags: linux, gcc, dynamic-library

I have a problem with an embedded linux C++ application I've written that consists of an executable and a dynamically linked library. The executable calls a function that is one of the entry points in the library, but that function  misbehaves. I've investigated using gdb, and find that the library function, which is supposed to make a call to another function xyz() within the library, actually calls a function of the same name xyz()within the executable.

I'm very surprised this can happen, so maybe I'm doing something stupid. Isn't the library linked within itself without reference to the executable? If the executable wrongly made a call to abc() in the library instead of abc() in the executable that would make slightly more sense, because it is at least linked with the library, although in that case would the linker spot the dual definition? Or prioritise the local function?

I could just rename my functions so none of them have matching names, but I'd like to understand what is going on. I don't have much experience in this area, or with the gcc tools. Firstly, is what I think is happening in the above scenario even possible?

Both the executable and the library make calls to another library.
The link command for the library I'm using is:

powerpc-unknown-linux-gnuspe-g++-4.9.3 aaa.o bbb.o [etc] -shared -o libmylibary.so -L ../otherlibpath -Wl,-rpath-link,../otherlibpath -lotherlibname

Comment: What about the linking command for the executable? Does it use `-rdynamic`?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: it doesn't use -rdynamic. It uses -Wl,-rpath-link,../ otherlibpath  -lotherlibname -Wl,-Bstatic -lxxx -Wl,-Bdynamic -lmylibrary where lxxx is a library it's statically linked to, and otherlib is the dynamic library they are both linked to that I mentioned above. Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 2):

That is way how the dynamic linker works. The symbols in executable have higher priority then symbols in dynamic libraries. Dynamic library designer must be aware about it. She must do measures to avoid unwanted symbol mismatch. Most libraries use:

- In case of C++ use namespaces. All symbols exported from library should be in a library namespace.
- In case of C use a name prefix or suffix for all exported symbol. For example OpenSSL library uses the prefix `SSL_` and the public functions have names like `SSL_set_mode()` so the unwanted symbol collision is avoided.
- Do not export symbols from the library that are supposed to be private. If the symbol is not exported from the library then the dynamic linker use the local symbol in the library. `#pragma visibility` is your friend. See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

If the library with duplicate symbols is a 3rd party library and its author does not follow the recommendations above then you have to rename your function or perhaps ask the author for a library update.

EDIT

Export/do not export may be controlled by `#pragma visibility` directive (gcc specific extension):

```
void exported_function1(int);
void exported_function2(int);
#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)
void private_function1(int);
void private_function2(int);
#pragma GCC visibility pop
```

Detail at the link above.

Comment: How do I prevent the executable exporting symbols? It seems to export all of them (looking with nm -D or readelf --dyn-syms), but I'd have thought an executable wouldn't normally want to export any..

Comment: Having experimented further, the function name symbols that are exported by the executable are exactly those that match function names in the dynamic library it is being linked with. To stop it, I've added -fvisibility=hidden to the compilation and link commands for the executable. So the problem is solved. The library now calls its own versions of the functions.

Comment: Well, it may work when you compile executable with `-fvisibility=hidden` because the library does not see the symbols in executable. But there is still potential to symbol mismatch between libraries. It is better to limit library symbol visibility - see the edit.